# How to exclude elements contained in another column - Pyspark DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

Imagine you have a **pyspark** data frame `df` with three columns: `A, B, C`. I want to take the rows in the data frame where the value of B does not exist in C.

Example:

```
A B C
a 1 2
b 2 4
c 3 6
d 4 8
```

would return

```
A B C
a 1 2
c 3 6
```

What I tried

```
df.filter(~df.B.isin(df.C))
```

I also tried to making the values of B into a list, but that takes a significant amount of time.

Comment: @Chris loc doesn't work in pyspark, you are thinking of pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you're using `isin`. For better or worse, `isin` can't actually handle another pyspark `Column` object as an input, it needs an actual collection. So one thing you could do is convert your column to a list :

```
col_values = df.select("C").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
df.filter(~df.B.isin(col_values))
```

Performance wise though, this is obviously not ideal as your master node is now in charge of manipulating the entire contents of the single column you've just loaded into memory. You could use a left anti join to get the result you need without having to transform anything into a list and losing the efficiency of spark distributed computing :

```
df0 = df[["C"]].withColumnRenamed("C", "B")
df.join(df0, "B", "leftanti").show()
```

---

Thanks to Emma in the comments for her contribution.

Comment: should that be `left_anti` instead of `leftsemi`?

Comment: And just like that, you figured it out :D Updating my answer now.

Comment: left_anti worked like a charm, thanks!